# Getting crash logs that I don't understand (React Native Expo)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, app-store, app-store-connect

I recently created an Expo app, which I am trying to publish to the Apple App Store. I was rejected because the app kept crashing on the iPhone. The Apple reviewers sent me crash logs that barely make sense to me here. Does anyone here know how to read these, and tell me how to read these?

Crash logs: [Crash Log #1](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple122/v4/67/aa/ad/67aaaded-fc56-9a93-185a-f5a88321fe6d/crashlog-68FB2552-4585-4A92-BCF4-7A83135A9126.txt?accessKey=1662730941_704524619339308931_Yg%2FaS%2BU5cP4Nciwv5zru7goMUg7GvUd%2Frv9skKPNuqHyvAinexHGc%2FQpXXw3hNQeRprzHr7X5KR15PzZmxinhs9LMIyjCnKQ4Blmik0l%2F313Wmz2CTCFY49bHps5%2FOupCuMR7Ml4BIzNctPz891Cx%2FOVqCzUOJfhNY4CCgKZEeIjU749feMsooaf%2FwRU5fYHpnV07PgneVuAhJrt7NKZMQ%3D%3D), [Crash Log #2](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple122/v4/e4/7b/a8/e47ba8c4-e71f-218c-b670-2400f1db0971/crashlog-655B27BA-6554-41D9-B5D9-B98347F5DA89.txt?accessKey=1662730941_5306980679003293791_LAK%2F2EqIu5Q1L895PeOREWm3tddmDliEmLB96GKFz0V%2FFKursTO%2F4vOWgk8%2BMbYdpzAgrFG89%2B0%2B5QuqemgWHvTAuoSO75W389kVn8QAvxL1zaEF1NKOA6XxJT0mWxHQILjA7g6lpDbe8K8Erb5GW82eCgtYVemQy8pDKDotONBkN2%2B%2BPYsokvZ5cxCwT6um32nLCraz70MvNAPZnBcAWA%3D%3D), [Crash Log #3](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple112/v4/4d/36/6b/4d366bb8-9db3-3704-d507-4d80cd2d6ab7/crashlog-C5EA3BDC-09DA-4875-B0ED-AC2A53771BE2.txt?accessKey=1662730941_6698489730204600660_i7fHnKY2%2BF7wSSL%2BftTZY%2B%2FaWWydAQRQUV9RXLUt7a31NA42kiAFz2Aa0R6N4mf4Nr5K8WwZxwlwiP5kPbqO7MEKAoUI84cTBADikiWijxK%2B6IjJvYMwaRyetGm7Pevy2DIXBV5uI7xcSKHpMwT5OsQnxHI9%2FtGVjwb8lfRbXMnU8VVR%2BtCCBIH6wINiaXklhispBVXmNNXyVIX8mHHk8Q%3D%3D), [Crash Log #4](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple112/v4/be/58/5b/be585bc4-b358-4927-bf1b-8549c6870a9b/crashlog-7560193A-8076-4CB5-AEB2-D0F5A7C03090.txt?accessKey=1662730941_2605381327951555307_uvAFKu378Mm9Gs5HPs7XLn7AkcLejsa5k0spd7BqeElgdULR%2B69KVQ5m0HA3ZK54e3hutXnaBZAcG0kw91LME%2BA2HdjkrfoillJ9h5TgrNmiThNsXX5uD2FLRKCtW7QFLHSD7VH8LzqfJa5%2FJ1AcqW68tXW7z%2BKxgXTUePi0PSgK70f8JzzI8y%2BQaHcz6XSVwZJR4MiZZBqnzg7unZPRDA%3D%3D), [Crash Log #5](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple122/v4/86/f5/0d/86f50db3-a0cf-3b88-2e3c-064a43bf22c2/crashlog-3EAADA38-3773-4B9B-A26D-CF7D2A3670B3.txt?accessKey=1662730941_3567502461159014044_OyCmzAakjicK2Qy0xBy%2B0zK1PyuJx4qY6hsLa2eOraYh1YR5YsL4op%2BEhuDDvk4qj%2B1Sue8qvHGCXOPHeYqwATlx9UUv6keLhZ%2FJuFqyHZwVTC3z3NxzD%2Fp0aIuHtj9Lzc3EXfp4EeCMGEwgVCxDqID1%2F2OzH0X0AIe9xIeHuaeunFinb5dy5H01QtS%2B8PQSOSkARjMwc9Rkx5vDb%2Bh1yg%3D%3D)

Comment: mmm this line tells me that might is an error in your code `"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},`  ... did you test your app in ios? are you in M1 arch?

Comment: I did test this on an Expo simulator, and it went fine. I do use an M1 Mac.

Comment: Anyone still have an answer to this?